# How can I limit file fragmentation while working with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, fragmentation

In my application I am gathering small data bits into a bigger file over time.  As a result, the target file becomes excessively fragmented.  What can be done to limit fragmentation of the output file with .NET?

Comment: Technical details: 32-bit Server 2003, 16GB output file size, 4K per cluster, a few MB per input file, 30K fragments observed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could deliberately increment the file size in larger chunks and internally monitor where the end of your current usage is. That way you give the system a better chance of allocating contiguous space for your file.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can reliably reduce file fragmentation is to allocate space for the complete file in one go (fill the rest of the file with zeros, as filler). But this can only be done if you have some idea of the final size of the file.

Another option would be to increase the file size by a certain value during each increment (say, 100 MB). That way you would have lesser defragmented chunks.